# PhpUnit dataProviders vs Coverage

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage

I decided, that it will be fine if I use data providers but when i try to generate code coverage whole tested class has 0% coverage.. Can someone tell me why?

Test class:

```
class AuthorDbManagerTest extends AbstractDbManagerTest
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider instanceOfProvider
     * @param bool $isInstanceOf
     */
    public function testInstances(bool $isInstanceOf)
    {
        $this->assertTrue($isInstanceOf);
    }

    public function instanceOfProvider()
    {
        $manager = new AuthorDbManager($this->getEntityManagerMock());
        return [
            "create()" => [$manager->create() instanceof Author],
            "save()" => [$manager->save(new Author()) instanceof AuthorDbManager],
            "getRepository" => [$manager->getRepository() instanceof EntityRepository],
        ];
    }
}
```

Tested class:

```
class AuthorDbManager implements ManagerInterface
{
    protected $entityManager;
    protected $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Author::class);
    }

    public function create(array $data = [])
    {
        return new Author();
    }

    public function getRepository(): EntityRepository
    {
        return $this->repository;
    }

    public function save($object): ManagerInterface
    {
        $this->entityManager->persist($object);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Why my code coverage is 0% on AuthorDbManager?
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBCcm.png)

Answer (score 0):

The data in the DataProvider is collected before the actual tests start - and there is nothing useful being tested within the testInstances() method.

If you passed the classname and expected class into `testInstances($methodName, $expectedClass)`:

```
public function testInstances(callable $method, $expectedClass)
{
    $this->assertInstanceOf($expectedClass, $method());
}
```

The dataprovider could return a callable, and the expected result:

```
"create()" => [[$manager,'create'], Author::class],
```

then you'd at least be running the code with in the actual test. You may also be better to just pass back a string methodname - 'create', and run that with a locally created $manager instance - `$manager->$method()` in the test.

In general, it's best to test something as specific as you can - not just letting it convert to a true/false condition.